# center argument must be a pair of numbers

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that the script generates a random x position for a shape that will be created.

I am rather new to python so I have no idea how to fix this.

Code section: (inside of pygame game loop)

```
class falling_object():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create():
        global random_x
        random_x = random.randint(10, 470)
        random_size = random.randint(20, 40)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), random_x, falling_y, random_size, random_size) # error is here at the random_x and random_size part, falling_y is a variable equal to 0
```

Where the function is called:

```
obj1 = falling_object()
falling_object.create()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center argument of [`pygame.draw.circle`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220219143739/https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) needs to be a tuple with the x and y coordinate:

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), random_x, falling_y, random_size, random_size)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), (random_x, falling_y), random_size)
```

---

Create the coordinates of the sphere in the constructor and draw the sphere in a mthod:

```py
class falling_object():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(10, 470)
        self.y = falling_y
        self.size = random.randint(20, 40)

    def create(self):
        self.y = falling_y
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.size)
```

Construct the sphere before the application loop, but draw it in the loop:

```py
obj1 = falling_object()

# [...]

while running:

    # [...]  

    obj1.create()
```